# Convert pem to jks on Mac

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, pem, jks

I want to hit a web service, they have shared ".p12" file and couple of ".pem" file, one with password and another one without password. While browsing the internet regarding how to hit the service with those certificate, found the following answer 
1) Convert the ".pem" to ".jks" then we can use ".jks" to hit the service.

So i followed the below step to convert ".pem" to ".jks"

1) Tried to convert the "No password" pem to ".jks" got the below exception

```
33585:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

2) So i tried to convert trusted ".pem" to ".jks"

```
i) openssl x509 -outform der -in aaa.pem -out aaa.der
ii) keytool -noprompt -importcert -alias aaa -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -file aaa.der
```

3) The above 2-steps was success, while performing 3rd step getting the following exception

```
i) keytool -exportcert -alias selfsigned -keypass password -keystore aaa.jks -rfc -file aaa.pem

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: aaa.jks
```

Any help should be appreciable. Also is there any other easy way or guided way to convert it ? Note : I am using mac

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww sorry I am not getting you.How come this question is not coming under programming & development ? Please correct me if i am wrong.I need the JKS keystore to continue my development. Also i am provided what i did so for. I saw lot of topics related to the same topic but nothing helps or i didn't interpret it properly.

Comment: If you need help with commands, then you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). If its a programming question, then maybe you should show your code.

Comment: Oh ok. Actually i have followed other similar set of questions and their tagging so i though we can raise the question with proper tagging is enough.Could you please guide me what shall i do next ? Shall i delete this question and raise a question in the forum you have shared ?

Comment: There's no reason for this question to be posted on a different platform. It belongs here as well.